# .postion in mm jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to .postion of jquery in mm rather tham px

```
$("#status_div").text("Offset Left:"+ui.offset.left.toFixed(0) + " Offset Top:" + ui.offset.top.toFixed(0)
                                        + " Position Left: "+ui.position.left.toFixed(0) +" Position Top: "+ui.position.top.toFixed(0) );
```

Comment: Your question is really unclear. Do you mean how do you *set* something's position in millimeters, or how do you *get* something's position in millimeters for display?

Comment: yes how do iget ones position when dragging in mm rather than px

Comment: @ user: To improve/clarify your question, use the "edit" link, not comments.

Answer (score 4):

In order to *get* the position in millimeters rather than pixels, the first thing you'll have to do is find out how many pixels/millimeter there are in the user's display (in each dimension). You can do that by creating an element, positioning it absolutely in `mm`, and then getting its position from `offset` (which will give it to you in pixels). For example:

```
var div = $("<div>").css({
    position: "absolute",
    left: "100mm",
    top: "100mm"
}).appendTo(document.body);
var pos = div.offset();
div.remove();
var pixelsPerMM = {
    x: pos.left / 100,
    y: pos.top  / 100
};
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/AKizuri/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/AKizuri/1/edit)

Then you can use `offset` (or `position` if you want the number relative to the parent positioning element) and do the math.

Comment: note, however, that CSS milimeters are only a crude approximation of the "real thing". Especially since CSS pixels don't neccessarily equate device pixels, chances are the observed resolution is always going to be 96 DPI.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Indeed, for the moment (and probably foreseeable future). And that's what I get with the above on my system: 3.78 pixels/mm, which is basically 96 DPI.

Comment: Even if screen manufacturers _were_ convinced to encode the screen physical size into their [DDCs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_Data_Channel) and the OSes were convinced to respect that, there's also the issue of what happens if the same content is shown on multiple screens at once (either split or duplicated). I would _hate_ to assume the physical size is a function of position and time when coding. Especially since we don't really seem to have a "window moved" event.

Answer (score 0):

**EXTEND jQuery's position function, I used its jQuery's own code and added px to mm multiplier**

**Explanation :-**

- Extend jQuery's Position method.
- To extend Download http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js.
- copy line code from line number  9632 to 9680 and add some chnage to it
- 1 px = 0.264583333 mm
- While returning the top & left multiply it by 0.264583333

  ```
  $(function (){
  var docElem = document.documentElement;
  jQuery.fn.extend({

  position: function() {
      if ( !this[ 0 ] ) {
          return;
      }
      var offsetParent, offset,
          parentOffset = { top: 0, left: 0 },
          elem = this[ 0 ];

      var pxToMmMultiplier = 0.264583333;

      if ( jQuery.css( elem, "position" ) === "fixed" ) {
          // we assume that getBoundingClientRect is available when computed position is fixed
          offset = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
      } else {
          // Get *real* offsetParent
          offsetParent = this.offsetParent();
          // Get correct offsets
          offset = this.offset();
          if ( !jQuery.nodeName( offsetParent[ 0 ], "html" ) ) {
              parentOffset = offsetParent.offset();
          }
          // Add offsetParent borders
          parentOffset.top  += jQuery.css( offsetParent[ 0 ], "borderTopWidth", true );
          parentOffset.left += jQuery.css( offsetParent[ 0 ], "borderLeftWidth", true );
      }
      return {
          top:  (offset.top  - parentOffset.top - jQuery.css( elem, "marginTop", true )) * pxToMmMultiplier,
          left: (offset.left - parentOffset.left - jQuery.css( elem, "marginLeft", true)) * pxToMmMultiplier
      };
  },

  offsetParent: function() {
      return this.map(function() {
          var offsetParent = this.offsetParent || docElem;
          while ( offsetParent && ( !jQuery.nodeName( offsetParent, "html" ) && jQuery.css( offsetParent, "position") === "static" ) ) {
              offsetParent = offsetParent.offsetParent;
          }
          return offsetParent || docElem;
      });
  }
  });

      $("#testPos").text(JSON.stringify(($("#testPos").position())));
      $("#testPos2").text(JSON.stringify(($("#testPos2").position())));
  });
  ```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZsMVa/1/)

Comment: Please clarify your answer. Just posting some code isn't a good answer. It needs an explaination.